# Present participle as a replacement for "that [verb]"

Tags: grammaticality, expression-choice, participles, present-participles

Are the following statements grammatically correct? If so, are they equivalent in meaning and which is more clear?

- "[subject] moves to a location **that acts** as the main [thing]..."
- "[subject] moves to a location, **acting** as the main [thing] ..."

Comment: (a) yes (b) no (the comma shifts the agent of 'acting as the main thing' to the referent of the subject. Dropping the comma ensures that the participial clause modifies 'a location'.

Comment: So without the comma in the second example, would they be equivalent?

Comment: You could perhaps insert a nail file between the two meanings. But I'm off to watch a travel programme.

Comment: To be clear, both sentences are *grammatical* (syntactically sound).